# How to fix "No overload matches this call." error when using passport.serializeUser?

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

I'm developing `passport.serializeUser` with TypeScript.

```ts
passport.serializeUser((user: User, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
});
```

This is the error I get:

```ts
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(fn: (user: User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(user: import("/Users/minseokim/Documents/dev/project/my-todo/models/user").default, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(user: Express.User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'user' and 'user' are incompatible.
        Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, email, password, nickname, and 31 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(fn: (req: IncomingMessage, user: User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(user: User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: IncomingMessage, user: User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'user' and 'req' are incompatible.
        Type 'IncomingMessage' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, email, password, nickname, and 30 more.
```

Comment: you need to provide more information please. What is the type definition of `serializeUser` ? It seems that there are two overloads of that method, and none of them match what you are passing into. Where is the type `User` coming from etc. Maybe a small typescript playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) would help to show your error

Answer (score 2):

What to do is extend the interface on a declaration file to add more overload, by using this code into `./types/passport.d.ts` file.

```
import { User } from '../models/Users' // export interface User { _id: string, ... }

declare module 'passport' {
  interface Authenticator {
    serializeUser<TID>(fn: (user: User, done: (err: any, id?: TID) => void) => void): void;
  }
}
```

and then config your `./tsconfig.json` with this.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./types"],
    ...
  }
}
```

Finally, your code should be work without error.

```
passport.serializeUser((user: User, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
});
```

Keep in mind you also can use `user: any` instead to prevent this error.